# Como combinar estos 2 botones para realizar solo 1 funcion?

Tags: html, jquery

Sucede que tengo estos botones que abren o cierran un DIV
pero la interaccion es un poco funky, y quisiera lograr algo mas fluido

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a id="showDeactivateAccountDetails" onClick="$('#deactivateAccount').slideDown(); $('#showDeactivateAccountDetails').slideUp(); $('#hideDeactivateAccountDetails').slideDown();" class="btn btn-sm btn-light rounded-pill mb-1"> Abrir Detalles </a>
<a id="hideDeactivateAccountDetails" onClick="$('#deactivateAccount').slideUp(); $('#hideDeactivateAccountDetails').slideUp(); $('#showDeactivateAccountDetails').slideDown(); " class="btn btn-sm btn-light rounded-pill mb-1"  style="display: none;"> Cerrar Detalles </a>
<div id="deactivateAccount" class="mt-2" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</div>
```

Pude realizar esta funcion, pero no se como ponerla en el onClick directamente

```
function showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails(){
        if($('#showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails').html() == "Abrir Detalles"){
            $('#showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails').html("Cerrar Detalles");
            $('#deactivateAccount').slideDown();
        }else{
            $('#showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails').html("Abrir Detalles");
            $('#deactivateAccount').slideUp();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva. Lo explico a continuacion:

En vez de usar dos hipervinculos, utilizamos un **input** de tipo boton y en el colocamos la funcion que se ejecutara con el evento **OnClick** sin pasarle ningun parametro, solo la funcion.

Previamente tienes tu DIV **deactivateAccount** oculto, entonces en la funcion JS **showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails** determinas que si el div está oculto, el valor de tu botón será "Mostrar Detalles" y le aplicas una transición con duracion de 300, la cual puedes aumentar/reducir el tiempo.

```js
 function showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails() {
        var div = document.getElementById("deactivateAccount");
        var button = document.getElementById("showDeactivateAccountDetails");
        if (div.style.display === "none") {
            $('#deactivateAccount').slideDown(300);
            div.style.display = "block";
            button.value="Ocultar Detalles";
        } else {
            button.value="Abrir Detalles";
            $('#deactivateAccount').slideUp(300);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="button" value="Abrir Detalles" id="showDeactivateAccountDetails" onClick="showAndHideDeactivateAccountDetails()" class="btn btn-sm btn-light rounded-pill mb-1"> 

<div id="deactivateAccount" class="mt-2" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</div>
```